# Make SharePoint 2010 site temporarily unavailable

Tags: access

We need to make live updates to a SharePoint 2010 site. By this I mean: creating/editing (new) site columns, creating/editing lists/content types etc.

How can we ensure that noone is able to access the site anymore besides administrators, ie make it temporarily unavailable?

Many thanks.

Comment: We usually do it in off hours using a tested script to make sure it doesn't break anything.

Comment: It is just a matter of creating new columns from the UI. We could use powershell but this is not an option at this point. People are accessing the SP from all over the world so we cannot do it outside business hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is to much work to create a solution to block the users. I would instead write a temporary message on the sites welcome page and temporary set the access rights for all groups (except Admins) to Read/Visitor. That way they will get informed of that you are "Working on it" and they will be able to see things but they will not be able to edit anything while You are working on the site.